# why doesn't s3 have a built-in "s3 buckets only" user group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created an S3 bucket and want to add a user to it. To add the user so that they can actually do stuff I need to add them to a group. So I try to create a group and when I search the pre-defined groups for groups that contain the phrase "S3" I find two:

**AmazonDMSRedshiftS3Role**: Provides access to manage S3 settings for Redshift ednpoints for DMS.

**AmazonEC2RoleforAWSCodeDeploy**: Provides EC2 access to S3 bucket to download revision. This role is needed by the Code Deploy agent on EC2 instances.

It just seems surprising that they don't have group that for S3-only access. Seems like that'd be a really common use case.

Maybe I'm missing something?